# How to simulate a hub?

Tags: linux, bridge

How can I simulate a hub on a Linux system? I know how to build bridge but I really need a hub behavior. My second solution is to use a bridge but I need to modify its behavior in order that it act as a hub. It is possible, for example, to disable the CAM table on a br0 interface?

Comment: Could you explain what you're trying to do that requires hub-like behaviour? You'll get better answers if we know what you're aiming for... (Are you just looking for a broadcast domain or is there more to it than that?)

Comment: @StephenKitt In fact, I receive mirrored traffic on a tap0 interface and I want to "broadcast" or mirror this traffic on other interface of my host.